# How to make assertions in R?

Tags: unit-testing, r, assertions

Is it recommendable to use *RUnit*'s check* functions to make preconditions/ postcondition statements or do this come with some penality in performance or other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but perhaps this answer will be useful to others looking for R assertions in operator form. This might be a step in the right direction if you want to tack an assertion onto the end of a troublesome statement.

```
"%assert%" <- function(e1, e2)
{

    args  <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
    defs  <- as.list(args$e1)
    preds <- as.list(args$e2)[-1L] 

    for(var in names(defs)[names(defs) != ""]) assign(var, eval(defs[[var]]))

    for(p   in unlist(preds)) eval(
        parse(
            text = paste0("if(!", deparse(p), ") stop('assertion ",deparse(p) , " is not true')")
        )
    )

    return(eval(args$e1))

}
```

**Example:** if you are computing the mean of a vector x and you want to make sure that each element is between one and ten you could use

```
mean(x = sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = T)) %assert% c(min(x) > 0 && max(x) < 11)
#5.62
```

If this condition isn't true, you'll get an informative(ish) error such as

```
mean(x = sample(11:20, size = 100, replace = T)) %assert% c(min(x) > 0, max(x) < 11)
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : assertion max(x) < 11 is not true
```

It's completely untested, so use at your own peril!

Answer (score 28):

I always use `stopifnot()` for assertions.

Comment: Seconded. It's easy, it's clear, it's in R Base and with that it's ubiquitous.

Comment: but suffers readability. I want to explain why the precondition failed and check* is simply beautiful _checkEquals(a, b, "a must be b")_

Comment: Alternatively using `if` + `stop` allows one to check a condition and give an error message.